# Three.JS | PerObject-Blur, What techniques can I use for GLSL/C to optimize code?

Tags: javascript, c, three.js, glsl, webgl

**UPDATE 2**

I've implemented custom attributes with THREE.js, influences come with each pass in the vertex shader aligned with position attribute, the best solution with minimal code.

> I will add the example later

**UPDATE 1**

This method sets alpha to vertexes influenced by the velocity range inside bounding box. I need tips to deal with GLSL code repetition pervertex, it is a bit strange to me?

Shall I use functions? How?

> https://jsfiddle.net/LeroyRon/uep9t1v1/#&togetherjs=MjBnNMFQFl

**Anyways I have this:**

```
//for .x
if (position.x > 0.0) {
    if (velocityPosition.x + (velocities.x*shutterSpeed) > boundingBoxMaxView.x) {
        influence = position.x/boundingBoxMax.x;
        velocityPosition.x += (velocities.x*shutterSpeed*influence);
    }
} else if (position.x < 0.0) {
    if (velocityPosition.x + (velocities.x*shutterSpeed) < boundingBoxMinView.x) {
        influence = position.x/boundingBoxMin.x;
        velocityPosition.x += (velocities.x*shutterSpeed);
    }
}

//for .y
if (position.y > 0.0) {
    //To-Do
} else if (position.y < 0.0) {
    //To-Do
}

//for .z
if (position.z > 0.0) {
    //To-Do
} else if (position.z < 0.0) {
    //To-Do
}
```

Now that I think about it, I'm doing the code a bit backwards.

**Old Post >**

I have an app where objects move fast and needs to be described better in terms of its motion, like flying saucers with blurs and light trails. How could I achieve this special effect?

I have started the base to the implementation [per-object-motion-blur](http://john-chapman-graphics.blogspot.ca/2013/01/per-object-motion-blur.html), along with the best docs that I could find, follow this link for Collab:

> https://jsfiddle.net/LeroyRon/uep9t1v1/#&togetherjs=DIo3kqhPfC

Could it be possible to have light blurs for lighter parts of the cube?

```
uniforms: {
        //velocity: {type: "f", value: velocity},
        //uVelocityScale: {type: "f", value: uVelocityScale},
        //speed: {type: "f", value: uVelocityScale},
        //nSamples: {}
      },
      //attributes: {

      //}
```

Answer (score 3):

Blur is a screenspace operation, so you need to run it once everything is rendered.
So, you need to output the "influence" somehow to a render buffer target so that you can have acess to it inside the screenspace blur

here's one https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdfGDH, the variable you want to tweak is mSize, and that should be coming from a texture outputed to a render target before.

That's why the tutorial you linked use a "velocity buffer", which stores velocities in screen-space so that it can be used by the screen space blur.

Anyway some tips on optimizations, but not sure the vertex shader code would pose any performance problems here anyway. Functions usage may not be a good path for optimization, best bet is math function optimisation and depending on GPU target, vectorization.

- What's your device target ? mobile and desktop have different GPU
- Faster BBox transform http://dev.theomader.com/transform-bounding-boxes/
- vectorization for example test on mutliple value of a vector https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/any.xhtml
- run glsl-optimizer on your shader once finished https://github.com/aras-p/glsl-optimizer

Note you miss 0 in your branches ( > 0 && < 0 but no == 0)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the [THREE.GPUComputationRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/cefe993143146ea2479fdbf3bfcf51ee1c856d83/examples/js/GPUComputationRenderer.js). You should be able to do exactly the content of the [per-object-motion-blur](http://john-chapman-graphics.blogspot.ca/2013/01/per-object-motion-blur.html) tutorial by rendering the object's position to a buffer (a texture) and then passing that buffer into the next round of calculations by passing in the texture - in this way you can compute blur values based on both the object's past and current positions.

Take a look at [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_gpgpu_birds) which doesn't do a blur, but does show how to use the GPUComputationRenderer to render out your positions as a texture (`sampler2D`) and then reference them in the next pass - exactly as your tutorial recommends. In this way you can precompute all sorts of values per vertex ahead of time and render the image based on those values (motion blurs, single object blurs, etc.).

As @Tuan Kuranes said, you can't do things like single object blur or motion blur in a single pass that is also computing everything else in your scene, but using the GPUComputationRenderer you can render out the image and values to help you do this in as few passes as possible. Good Luck!!